# VSTO Starting EXCEL in code

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-2010

I am trying to start a new instance of Excel application using this lines of code :

```
excelApp = new MSExcel.Application();
((MSExcel.Application)excelApp).Visible = true;
```

But the applicatin starts only for few seconds. It doesn't happen in word using same code . Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: This isn't VSTO, it's just plain old interop, lol...

Comment: do you need to control the excel application - or just to start it?

Comment: Does the EXCEL.EXE process show in Task Manager or does the process immediately quit? Are you trying to show a blank Excel file?

Comment: I'm just trying to open an excell application that has VSTO addin installed which automatically starts along with the Excel app so I just need to open excel but it automatically closes after 1 - 2 seconds and yes I can see it in the Task manager.

Answer (score 0):

The following code opens word document

```
wordApp = new Word.Application();
wordObject.Documents.Open(FileName: fileName, ReadOnly: isReadOnly);
wordObject.Visible = true;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question .

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, your comments above makes very clear now. It looks like your addin crashes your application. Some properties are not accessible when you automate the excel which has addin. I tried to display error message and another application which automates excel crashed everytime because it was in invisible mode. Try this steps to get the error message http://www.macroview.com.au/support/KnowledgeBase/Pages/20110084.aspx